# Promise in Promise function: Can't push data into Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am using sequelizeJS. I have a Promise in Promise function. I want to make a Promise function to get data, then push this data into Array and return this Array.

I tried with this code but it's not success.

```
function sequelize_conversation (conversation_id, req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var response = []
    for (let id of conversation_id) {
      db.ConversationPerson.findAll({ where: {'conversation_id': id, 'user_id': { [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id }} })
      .then(person => {
        console.log(person) // results: { 'id': 1, 'name': 'John' }
        response.push(person.dataValues)
      })
    }
    resolve(response)
  })
}
```

Result I get:

`response = []`

But I want to get:

`response = [{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'John' }]`

Please review my code and help me understand about Promise in Promise function. Thank you in advance!

Comment: promises imply asynchronous code ... you are resolving before any of the `db.ConversationPerson.findAll` has a chance to do anything, let alone complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

promises imply asynchronous code ... you are resolving before any of the `db.ConversationPerson.findAll` has a chance to do anything, let alone complete

Your code is actually a lot simpler than you think

```
function sequelize_conversation (conversation_id, req) {
    var promises = [];
    for (let id of conversation_id) {
      promises.push(
        db.ConversationPerson.findAll({ where: {'conversation_id': id, 'user_id': { [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id }} })
        .then(data => {
          return data.dataValues
        })
      );
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Or if conversation_id is an actual Array, and adding a little bit of ES6+ goodness

```
const sequelize_conversation = (ids, req) => Promise.all(
    ids.map(conversation_id => 
        db.ConversationPerson.findAll({ 
            where: {
                conversation_id, 
                'user_id': { 
                    [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id 
                }
            }
        })
        .then(({dataValues}) => dataValues)
    )
);
```

Comment: I just want to push `dataValues` field only, bro

Comment: well ... I'm using the code you posted `db.ConversationPerson.findAll({ where: {'conversation_id': id, 'user_id': { [Op.ne]: req.user.user_id }} })` - you claim `person` in the `.then` is what you want ... so, that's what the code above will resolve to

Comment: i.e. I haven't changed what goes into the array (well, sort of) ... I've changed it so that it has a chance to get there - your db functions are your code ... bro

Comment: or, put another way ... if your code `console.log(person) // results: { 'id': 1, 'name': 'John' }` is accurate .. then my code will work ... where are you putting the `console.log` in my code?

Comment: Thank you. I made it success. I will fullfill your code!

Comment: what was wrong with my code? don't accept it if the code is wrong!!

Comment: No. Your code works like a charm. I just fullfill it. Please review

Comment: So, your original code must also do `response.push(person.dataValues)` @FeedGit and `console.log(person.dataValues)`

Comment: Ok bro. Fixed this